# Randomizing the display order of content using AMP

Tags: amp-html

currently experimenting with amp. Using JavaScript, we can jiggle things up, and display pieces of content that randomly interchange order. The result is a group of content that randomly changes display position each time the page is loaded, allowing each of them to receive equal attention from viewers.However i cant use JS so looking to create something similar in AMP.

Comment: From here, you need to check first the [AMP documentation](https://www.ampproject.org/learn/overview/). There are 3 core components composed of AMP HTML, AMP JS, AMP Cache]. This will more likely be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can.
Use amp-bind/amp-list/amp-mustache combination with a JSON endpoint.
The endpoint giving you the content dynamically.

If you just want to change the position, you can add classes with amp-bind and something like

```
[CLASS]='position ? "newPosition" : "" '
```